# Unable to create new Test Plan in VSTS

Tags: testing, azure-devops

For the past day, the 'New Test Plan' button has been missing from our VSTS UI inside the Test-Test Plans area. I also can't find anywhere else in VSTS giving the option to create a new test plan. (I'm sure there used to be a few places, but they were obvious, and now missing)

Could it be anything to do with star symbol showing in the UI after ' Test Plans* ', like some changes need saving somewhere before new test plans can be added? In which case, what changes should I be looking for to save?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally Test plan creation is limited to users subscribed to Test Manager extension or VS/MSDN subscribers.

> Basic license users can only run tests. You need a valid Visual Studio
>   subscription (Enterprise, Test Professional or MSDN Platforms) or Test
>   Manager license ($52 monthly):
>   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web
>   to create test plans.
>
> **See this thread : [Can't add a new test plan](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80055/cant-add-a-new-test-plan.html)**

So please check if you have the license to create the test plan, and for an **paid extension** you must assign that extension to users who need access, so they can start using that extension's capabilities. Please see [Assign paid extension access to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/assign-paid-extensions?view=vsts)

Whatever, I can reproduce the issue on myside, seems it's an issue with the preview feature.

**As a workaround** you can create the Test Plan with [MTM (Microsoft Test Manager)](https://beeming.net/visual-studio/2017/3/so-i-installed-vs-enterprise-2017-and-have-no-mtm-where-is-it) or [REST API (Test Plans - Create)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20%20plans/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0). Both work for me, but the test plan will not display immediately after creating it, you may need to wait for several minutes to sync it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andy - very helpful